# Amazon S3 bucket images return 403 error

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've just inherited a rails site hosted on heroku using S3 for storage of images uploaded with the paperclip gem and suddenly most images are returning 403 errors.  Looking at the bucket through the management console, I don't see the files listed even.

The images are uploaded through the ckeditor wysiwyg plugin, and it looks like they should be inside a folder named 'rich', but no such folder exists within the bucket. Not all files are missing (though some that were throwing a 403 are now showing up on the site correctly without me having done anything I can think of to change that), but none of them are listed in the management console.

I'm unfamiliar with S3 and not sure how to diagnose let alone resolve this issue.  Any suggestions on steps I can do to figure out what the problem is would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue. Are you logged into AWS using the main account credentials? If not can you try that and see if you see all the files there?

Comment: It's the main account from the client. From what I'm told, everything worked fine at one point and no one claims to have done anything with the account

Comment: Weird, the bucket name is the right one ? Is it possible that the heroku app did something to the bucket with its permissions and now you can't see it with your account ?  Heroku probably has its own way of interacting with S3.

Comment: I am also having the same error

Answer (score 1):

Every time I've seen this error, it has been permissions:

1. Triple-check your AWS Access_key, Secret_key, and REGION

If you have any doubt about the keys, regenerate a new set to be sure you are using the correct keys.

1. If you end up changing any of them, remember to restart your server to re-read the values.